# Life Cycle Tools Suite

Tags: version-control, project-management, lifecycle, issue-tracking

I am looking to replace the life cycle tools currently used by my development teams.
Tools that I'm looking for:

- Version Control
- Defect/Issue Tracking
- Requirements Tracking
- Test Case Management
- (potentially) Project Management: Project Status, hours entry

I have a new beefy server (Windows 2008 Server) to run all tools on.  I'm looking at COTS and Open Source options, but haven't decided so far.

Other factors:

- Distributed team (different physical sites)
- Some Windows Development, some Linux Development
- Software, Firmware, Technical Writing need to be able to use it

Recommendations on a good suite that will work together?
If Open Source, best approach to run on the Windows 2008 Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most common choice for version control system is [Subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/). It has good tool support, most tools work with Subversion out of the box.

You have a distributed team so you might consider a distributed version control system. For example [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/) or [Git](http://git-scm.com/). Mercurial has better support on Windows. Tool support is bit lacking compared to "traditional" version control systems like [Subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/).

All of the above are open source.

For project management/issue tracking/requirements tracking there is open source [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) which is combined issue tracker, project management software and wiki. Trac work with Subversion, Git and Mercurial.

Atlassian provides commercial [JIRA](http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/) for issue tracking/project management and [Confluence](http://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence/) for wiki. Jira works at least with Subversion.

Fog Creek has Mercurial based [Kiln](http://www.fogcreek.com/Kiln/) for version control and [FogBugz](http://www.fogcreek.com/fogbugz/) for issue tracking/project management. Both commercial. Both are available as hosted and as run-on-your-own-server versions.

I have used Trac, which works, but you can expect some tinkering and configuration before it work like you want it to work.

Comment: Not a personal fan of FogBugz, but we did end up going with Subversion and it worked really well for us.

Answer (score 3):

Svn/Trac plus a few plugins will probably get you most of the way there for free.

If you use the version supplied by visualsvn (they bundle both trac and subversion) its a nice easy setup too.

http://www.visualsvn.com/server/
http://trac.edgewall.org/
http://trac-hacks.org/

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the tools by Atlassian- http://www.atlassian.com/ we've used some of their products (Jira/Confluence) and they link together well. Not exactly expensive either.

As an admin / Wiki gardener they are easy to use and manage, which can sometimes be an important over looked requirement.